# キーイベントやマウスクリックイベントの疑似的発火について

Tags: javascript, jquery

現在jqueryを使用してブラウザアプリを開発しているのですが。
ブラウザの機能としてCtrl+マウスホイールで拡大縮小ができると思います。(chromeやIE)
これをボタンに置き換えたいと思っています。
例えば"+"ボタンを配置し、これが押されたらあたかも[Ctrl+マウスホイール奥へ一回コロコロ]がされたとブラウザに認識させたいのです。
cssを使い $("html").css("zoom", "90%");などのやり方も発見したのですが、
これでは不都合になってしまったため質問しました。

このように実際にその操作はしていなくても[ctrlボタンが押された]や[マウスホイールが動かされた]という動作を意図的に行うことはできるのでしょうか？

詳しい方いましたらご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cssを使い $("html").css("zoom", "90%");などのやり方も発見したのですが、
>   これでは不都合になってしまったため質問しました。

具体的にはどのような不都合が生じたのでしょうか。

[Ctrl] + [+] によるページズームをCSS/JavaScriptから直接操作する手段はおそらく用意されていないと思います。
この機能は目の不自由なユーザがページ拡大して読みやすくしたり、逆に大きすぎる文字を小さくする事で視認性を上げたり、とユーザのためにある機能です。
この機能をWeb製作者がコントロールできるとユーザの意図しないところでページ拡大率を変動させる事が可能になってしまいます。
(@user20198 さんにその意図がなくてもそのように実装できてしまう事が問題です。)

Comment: 不都合としては、作成しているアプリではダイアログやスライダーを実装しています。 これらのUIはあるライブラリを使用して表示しているんですが、そのライブラリ側ではどうやらcssによる拡大縮小の状態が認識されていない様なのです。　普段の動作ではダイアログの位置はウィンドウの真ん中に出るはずが位置がずれていたり、スライダーは摘みの位置がずれてしまっている状態です。　[Ctrl]+[+]を使用した場合はズレは起きなかったのでなんとかできないかと思ったのですが厳しいのですね、、、、

Comment: そういう事情でしたら、zoomプロパティが期待通りに動作するよう当該ライブラリを修正するのが現実解かもしれませんね…。

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key
こちらのEntryを参考にCtrl+＋を発行してみて
onkeypress内にてctrlがtrueになっている43(+キーのはず)のイベントが来ることは確認しましたが、
Zoomは発生しませんでしたね・・・

```
var oEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

// Chromium Hack
Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'keyCode', {
            get : function() {
                return this.keyCodeVal;
            }
});     
Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'which', {
            get : function() {
                return this.keyCodeVal;
            }
});

oEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, true, false, 43, 43);

oEvent.keyCodeVal = 43;

document.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
```

送り先のelementがdocumentになっているのでブラウザに割り当てられた機能としては働かない気がします。

Comment: 参考にさせて頂き試してみましたが同じくできませんでした。やはりブラウザの機能を操作するのはできない様ですね、ありがとうございます。